# Airflow dag short circuit using python

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a task 1 and task 2
My requirement is that if any of the 2 task gets failed need to wait for 7 hours before marking the dag completed using short circuit

Answer (score 0):

try to define **retries** and **retry_delay** in dag, set retry_delay for 7 hours [ref](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#example-pipeline-definition)

Note! this is setting in dag-level, not in task-level

[image]